# how to perform Nunit after asp.net web application is created

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, testing, nunit

I have created one web application which includes login page and several other pages which include input controls.How i can perform Nunit testing on this pages.

It will be very helpful if you provide guideline for just only login page.
Login page is created using Login.aspx and Login.aspx.cs file.

It is not created using MVC.

Comment: NUnit is for compiled unit tests. Are you asking about testing the functionality of the code that runs these pages? Or UI testing?

Comment: @Simon is correct, you can run nunit on your .cs classes.  For your web pages, you'd need something that will do a ui test.  Perhaps selenium.

Comment: I have never performed any testing before. So i don't know weather I have to extract login button[exec query and check user] logic using refractor an put it in separate .cs file .
let me know how i can perform testing on my login.aspx.cs file.. 
In App_code .cs file deal with sql server

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing [unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) with automated UI testing. NUnit, as its name states is for creating automated tests for separated pieces of code. With this tests you check if concrete piece of code does what it should do. To check this you substitute all its dependencies (all classes/interfaces it interacts with) with [stubs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_stub)/[mocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) ([more](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html)) which place the role of placeholders for real functionality. Thanks to this you can check if tested class behaves the way you expect it to behave because you have full control over its dependencies, so the only "unknown behavior" comes from object under test.

If you, however would like to automatize tests of user interface you can use special environments dedicated for this task. You can easily find dozens of frameworks for this, one of which is [FitNess](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.SliM)